# Сервер на Java. Какие есть фреймворки?

Tags: java, сервер

Здравствуйте. 
Собралась небольшая команда разработчиков. Хотим сделать сервис. Сервер решили писать на Java, т.к. знаем си-подобные языки, и нужна будет нетривиальная обработка данных на сервере. Можно было бы создать на шарпе, но это очень дорого (пиратить не хочется).
Но и не хочется писать на голой java то, что наверняка было сделано до нас. Возможно, есть хорошие фреймворки, которые смогут нам помочь. 
Расскажите, пожалуйста, в какую сторону смотреть, чем пользуетесь Вы?

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте смотрел в сторону пхп =)

Comment: Вы бы для начала подумали, чего вы хотите от фреймворка. А в текущем варианте вопрос очень расплывчатый.

Comment: джавист должен знать [Spring ][1]


  [1]: http://spring.io/

Comment: @andrw побольше конкретики нужно: что за сервис? Что он (приблизительно) должен выдавать на гора? Если просто тупо через http - это одно, а если что-то через хитрые сокеты/датаграммы - то другое. И что будет в бэкенде - какой SQL сервер или без?

Answer (score 2):

Я бы посоветовал посмотреть в сторону [Netty](http://netty.io)

Answer (score 0):

В этой области Spring занимает около 70% процентов рынка, еще около 20 - EJB (enterprise java beans). Мне больше по душе Spring, но тут, как говорится, на вкус и цвет фломастеры разные.

Еще Вам наверняка пригодится Spring Security (это отдельная либа) для того, чтобы не изобретать заново велосипеды в области обеспечения безопасности, а также Spring Data или Hibernate для работы с базами данных.

Comment: Сразу видно - человек, кроме Spring, в руках ничего не держал :)